# What is the use of .range field when updating a buffer descriptor?

Tags: vulkan

When I went to update a UNIFORM_BUFFER descriptor, I set up the buffer info:

```
VkDescriptorBufferInfo buffer_info;
buffer_info.buffer = /* SOME BUFFER */;
buffer_info.offset = 0;
buffer_info.range = 0; // I assume this doesn't do any thing for this use
```

And then vkUpdateDescriptorSets().

Get the validation layer error:

> VkDescriptorBufferInfo range is not VK_WHOLE_SIZE and is zero, which
> is not allowed.. The Vulkan spec states: If range is not equal to
> VK_WHOLE_SIZE, range must be greater than 0

My question is, isn't the job of the buffer info to tell which buffer and what offset to read from the shaders at a particular descriptor set and binding? I didn't think the size of the buffer mattered because generally that's how these things work, you usually specify a buffer and offset and then you read outside that buffer in the shader at your peril.

Let's just I write the wrong range, what would that do? If I write a 32 and in the shader I access 64 bytes in, what happens? Is this argument for validation warnings?

Edit: I just want to clarify the range argument can't mean how much of the buffer I want to copy, what I'm writing to is essentially a pointer. The actual writing of the buffer data is done in a buffer to buffer copy transfer.

Answer (score 3):

A descriptor describes a (usually memory) resource being used by a shader in some capacity. Buffers do have a size, but a shader can use a *subset* of a buffer's memory range. The descriptor describes which portion of the buffer is being used.

If a descriptor should use the whole size of the buffer assigned to it (starting at `offset`), that's what `VK_WHOLE_SIZE` is for.

This allows you to have multiple uniform buffers provided by the same `VkBuffer` resource. You can even use dynamic uniform block descriptors to change the offset/range without changing the buffer binding itself. This is faster than switching descriptor sets, thus making it easier to provide per-object data.

> Let's just I write the wrong range, what would that do?

If the range is smaller than the size of the uniform block specified in the shader, then you'll get a validation failure/undefined behavior.

Comment: Well I saw the writing of the uniform buffer descriptor as a pointer to the buffer and the offset, I still don't get why the range matters. Isn't it like binding the vertex buffer? You specify the buffer and the offset. Then you send it a vertex stream, and you read past the buffer at your own risk. Wouldn't the .range requirement be like requiring you to specify which range of the vertex buffer will be read during input processing?

Comment: @Zebrafish: "*Isn't it like binding the vertex buffer?*" No. Also, be aware that some descriptor resources like SSBOs are not bounded in the shader. Their bounds comes from what memory range you specify in the descriptor.

Comment: Alos, you *can* safely use out-of-range accesses if you have `robust_buffer_access` enabled.  This can be use to emulate DX behavior which clamps accesses to the active range. So the range is more than just a hint here - it's defines the limits that get clamped.